# Changing user in .bashrc breaks SFTP

Tags: linux, bash, sftp

In my learning track for Amazon EC2, I thought it would be a great idea to just always become the root user while still logging in. I added this line to my .bashrc

```
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/bash
```

That way, I would not have to SSH in as the root user, but I would be automatically switched when I log in. However, when this was in the .bashrc, it broke any SFTP client that tried to connect. The errors varied depending on the client used, but usually they all ended up with a timeout, even though they successfully connected to the remote host. WinSCP suggested that an SFTP server might not be running on the host.

I am now fully aware that adding that line was a bad move, but I don't know why this breaks SFTP. I'm logging in as ec2-user, but becoming root (I think), yet I can't understand why this causes a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash world, profile init files often calls rc init files as explained in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment). Hence rc init files are not bound to interactive-only shells.

To my knowledge, SFTP protocol is a non-interactive usage of SSH shell to execute a sftp-server program which interacts with the caller through its `stdin` and `stdout` streams. About your issue, I guess one of the two unwanted things happens:

- `sudo` command asks for a password, which is unexpected by sftp client which expects a binary interaction with its sftp-server colleague
- root user has no access to the binary called by sftp layer (because of permission settings - but I guess this is the sudo case)

You should have two ways to workaround this:

- restrict your root auto-switch to interactive-shells only as Martin suggests, for example using using [tty](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tty.1.html) command:

  ```
  if tty --silent
  then
      /usr/bin/sudo /bin/bash
  fi
  ```
- or create/modify your private .bashprofile to not call your rc file from it (still setting your PATH at least).

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the `.bashrc` is sourced and afterwards a shell or an SFTP server is started.

But your `.bashrc` never finishes, as it starts a shell on its own. So the SFTP server is never started.

Consequently, the SFTP client either times out waiting for an SFTP protocol handshake; or fails trying to decode some random shell output as an SFTP packet.

---

One possible workaround would be to use `sudo` for interactive sessions only (i.e. not for the non-interactive SFTP sessions).

Though normally the `.bashrc` should be sourced for interactive sessions only. So it should not intervene with SFTP. Your server seems to be misconfigured somehow.